# What are the best methods to share files among 2 different VM

Tags: linux, windows, network-share, synchronization

What are the best methods to automate the exchange files between 2 servers VM on the same LAN on the cloud?

A VM is windows server and B VM is CentOS Linux OS, the direction path is Windows Server Dir > CentOS Linux Dir, data size is around 5MB one way.

I need daily sync file service, I have options to discuss:

1. WinSCP Third party program
2. Shared SMB files (Samba and Windows SMB)
3. Syncthing Third Party program
4. Powershell Script that automate the sync service running over period time from windows to Linux

The main criteria is security and performance, I need stable option that could work 24/7. Please answer with your method if that does not listed above.

Comment: Your architecture is not clear as you say the 2 VMs are "on the same LAN on the cloud". Some questions that would help in deciding this: How much data is moving between the servers? It this a one-way sync or two-way (it seems to be one way from what you've written)? Without more information, I'd go with Syncthing as it's fast and secure and will be the easiest to set up as you don't need to create and manage any scheduled tasks in Windows.

Comment: Thanks you dear, I just updated the question,

Comment: If they're on the same network on a cloud provider, why not just share the directory from the Windows server and have the CentOS host mount the SMB share and access the live files? It's very difficult to suggest anything without more context.

Comment: Depending on the cloud provider, they may have a shared storage service in their portfolio. Otherwise, @Quetza's suggestion seems to be the simplest: Very little setup required, no scripts or command invocations needed except for a simple copy on the Windows side. CIFS should come installed in Centos.

Comment: if its at least win10/2016 nfs will work on both, if you wanna sync the same file with the same location but only difference either rsync or rdiff may you also choice. depending from which to which os should be transferred

Comment: from my experience Windows needs to authenticate from time to time by SMB Sometimes it's stopped  awe without prior notification or alert, because we are on production and Online 24/7 store you could affect many customers due to that fail of sync.

Comment: The direction is clear Windows Server has small XML file it will synced to Linux Centos VM, I used Shared File using SMB but as I mentioned there is a threat to by stopping this service with no prior alert. I need stable and secure method, we exploit multiple vulnerabilities in SMB and gain more info using this protocol, so my criteria is Secure and Stable method.

Answer (score -1):

Syncthing is a program open source that sync every file that you need in bidirectional manner, the key feature is that program could store and retention your files up to 1 year to keep backup of your file, which is lack with winscp, of SMB share, the last mentioned tool is to transfer medium only not to Sync service, the more feature provided and could count on so If any problem happened with previously synced file you could have a backup for that.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer? It does not look like one.

Comment: *"program could store and retention your files up to 1 year"* – What do you mean by that? Do you mean that the program should backup the files that were deleted as part of the synchronization?